# XML Schema for xslt2.0

Tags: xml, visual-studio-2010, xsd, xslt-2.0

I have copy-pasted xslt2.0 schema from "http://www.w3.org/2007/schema-for-xslt20.xsd" to VSTS 2010 location "c:/programfile(x86)/MS VSTS 10.0/xml/schema/xslt2.xsd". Now, when i try xsl:result-document, i m still not able to use it.

Is there something i need to modify after copying this schema? 
Can somebody please explain how to make this work(in detail)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 or XmlPrime or AltovaXML if you want to use XSLT 2.0. Microsoft does not support XSLT 2.0. See https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-2.0/info for links with download information for the named processors.